# Arch Server running VNC no longer displaying anything

Tags: vnc, arch-linux

I have a server running arch, kernel 4.13 that I remote into on a fairly frequent basis. I remote in via a VNC which I have as tigervnc. This has worked for months on end with very little issue. I power the VNC with KDE (Plasma Desktop).

After running into some issues with the server a few days ago, I upgrade everything and then reboot. After rebooting, I am able to start up the VNC and remote in, but cannot actually see anything. Cursor works and such but no context menus when I click anywhere, no GUI, no desktop, nada.

I have reinstalled KDE, tried running it as LXDE (in hopes that it was a KDE problem), reinstalled tigervnc, rebooted, everything. Below is my xstartup file though I dont think that is the issue. I also have my logs from the vnc below as well.

xstartup

```
#!/bin/sh

unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
#OS=`uname -s`
#if [ $OS = 'Linux' ]; then
#  case "$WINDOWMANAGER" in
#    *gnome*)
#      if [ -e /etc/SuSE-release ]; then
#        PATH=$PATH:/opt/gnome/bin
#        export PATH
#      fi
#      ;;
#  esac
#fi
#if [ -x /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc ]; then
#  exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
#fi
#if [ -f /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc ]; then
#  exec sh /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
#fi
#[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
#xsetroot -solid grey
#xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#twm &

startkde &
```

VNCServer Logs

```
Copyright (C) 1999-2017 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.txt)
See http://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Underlying X server release 11905000, The X.Org Foundation


Sat Dec 30 22:33:57 2017
 vncext:      VNC extension running!
 vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on all interface(s), port 5901
 vncext:      Listening for HTTP connections on all interface(s), port 5801
 vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
startkde: Starting up...
OpenGL vendor string:                   VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string:                 llvmpipe (LLVM 5.0, 256 bits)
OpenGL version string:                  3.0 Mesa 17.3.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
Driver:                                 Unknown
GPU class:                              Unknown
OpenGL version:                         3.0
GLSL version:                           1.30
Mesa version:                           17.3.1
X server version:                       1.19.5
Linux kernel version:                   4.13.12
Requires strict binding:                no
GLSL shaders:                           yes
Texture NPOT support:                   yes
Virtual Machine:                        no
Service started, version: 7.0.0
Service started, version: 7.0.0
2017-12-30T22:34:23 Checking update-file '/usr/share/kconf_update/disable_kmix.upd' for new updates
2017-12-30T22:34:23 Checking update-file '/usr/share/kconf_update/fonts_akregator.upd' for new updates
2017-12-30T22:34:23 Checking update-file '/usr/share/kconf_update/fonts_global.upd' for new updates
2017-12-30T22:34:23 Checking update-file '/usr/share/kconf_update/fonts_global_toolbar.upd' for new updates
2017-12-30T22:34:23 Checking update-file '/usr/share/kconf_update/fonts_kate.upd' for new updates
2017-12-30T22:34:23 Checking update-file '/usr/share/kconf_update/gtkbreeze5.5.upd' for new updates
2017-12-30T22:34:23 Checking update-file '/usr/share/kconf_update/kde4breeze.upd' for new updates
2017-12-30T22:34:23 Checking update-file '/usr/share/kconf_update/krdb_libpathwipe.upd' for new updates
2017-12-30T22:34:23 Checking update-file '/usr/share/kconf_update/krunnerplugins.upd' for new updates
2017-12-30T22:34:23 Checking update-file '/usr/share/kconf_update/kscreenlocker.upd' for new updates

Sat Dec 30 22:34:25 2017
 Connections: accepted: 10.40.1.109::57186
 SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.8
 SConnection: Client requests security type VeNCrypt(19)
 SVeNCrypt:   Client requests security type TLSVnc (258)

Sat Dec 30 22:34:28 2017
 VNCSConnST:  Server default pixel format depth 24 (32bpp) little-endian rgb888
 VNCSConnST:  Client pixel format depth 24 (32bpp) little-endian rgb888
ERROR: Back In Time is not configured!

Sat Dec 30 22:34:41 2017
 Connections: closed: 10.40.1.109::57186 (Clean disconnection)
 EncodeManager: Framebuffer updates: 18
 EncodeManager:   Tight:
 EncodeManager:     Solid: 1 rects, 786.432 kpixels
 EncodeManager:            16 B (1:196609 ratio)
 EncodeManager:   Total: 1 rects, 786.432 kpixels
 EncodeManager:          16 B (1:196609 ratio)
 TLS:         TLS session wasn't terminated gracefully
 ComparingUpdateTracker: 0 pixels in / 0 pixels out
 ComparingUpdateTracker: (1:-nan ratio)
```

Comment: What exactly does the screen look like?  What do the server logs say?

Comment: It is literally just black. And as far as server logs, I am not terribly sure how to get the ones you want via terminal (I am still struggling to learn journal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant explain why it happened, but after a few days of digging through logs, I found that the compositor that was being used was OpenGL2.0 and that just wasnt working for Kwin.

I loaded up a different window manager (openbox is what I used) and was able to load up the VNC just fine. Changing the Compositor to XRender now allows me to use Kwin again.